# Listbox - selected item to call the class method directly using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem scenario like this:-

1) Listbox with values like Car, Scooter and Bike. A button to click.

```
    <div>
<asp:ListBox ID="lst" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Bike" Value="Bike"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Car" Value="Car"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Scooter" Value="Scooter"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Invoke" />
</div>
```

2) Now i have three different class like below:-

```
 class Car
{
    static string getData()
    {
        return "I like cars";
    }
}

class Bike
{
    static string getData()
    {
        return "I like Bike";
    }
}

class Scooter
{
    static string getData()
    {
        return "I dont like scooter";
    }
}
```

3) Now on the button click event handler "Button1_Click", i want to call the getData() method based on the selected value from the listbox using the **REFLECTION only**.

Please help me out.

Comment: Not to judge you, but wouldnt it be better to create an interface and implement those on all three classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string data = (string)Type.GetType("MyAwesomeNamespace." + "Car").GetMethod("getData").Invoke(null, null);
```

1. `Type.GetType` gets your Type. You might want to prefix this with your namespace
2. `GetMethod` gets the getData method
3. `Invoke` will execute the method. Since the method is static, invoking the method with null will work. If it wasn't static, null had to be replace with your instance of that object. Also, the second null serves as the parameters, which are none in this case

Comment: how do i get the return string from the method.                 lbl1.Text  = Type.GetType(sValue).GetMethod("getData").Invoke(null, null);. This statement is not working. Do i need to cast something here?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your comment ;)

Comment: invoke method does not take one argument.

Comment: This is still giving me error:- protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sValue = lst.SelectedValue;
            lbl1.Text = (string)Type.GetType(sValue).GetMethod("getData").Invoke(null, null);

        }

Comment: Type.GetType gets your Type. You might want to prefix this with your namespace. So you cannot just put in "Car". Prefix it with your namespace, so if Car is in "MySystem.Vehicles", Type.GetType(sValue) should be Type.GetType("MySystem.Vehicles." + sValue)

Comment: i think something more is required to invoke the static method.

Comment: No there isn't.. What kind of exception are you getting? Also check the Invoke description on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

Comment: Ah one last detail: make your methods public, and not internal as they are now.

Comment: i made the methods public also.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
because Type.GetType is returning null.

Comment: Did you insert your namespace in the parameter of GetType?

Comment: At last, it is working now :-). public Method and namespace is needed. Many thanks.

Comment: one quick thing. What if my method is not static. How do i invoke that?

Comment: The first parameter of the Invoke method will need to be your instance of that object. So any instance will do. But if you need to do that, perhaps its wiser to implement an interface :)